# CAKEPHP- Database based navigation on every page

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

i´m new in CakePHP so apologize me, if it is a stupid question.

I´m trying to show dynamic navbar based on database. I´ve created a working Model/Controller/View setup based on database. But now i want to show the navbar on every page.

Is there a way to import "view into view" ?

My code: [view]

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">  
<?php 
$dropend = false;
foreach ($Navbar as $navlink) 
    {
        if($navlink->parent_id == 0)
        {
            if($navlink->rght - $navlink->lft == 1){
                echo'
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">'.$navlink->name.'</a></li>';
            } else {
                echo'
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">'.$navlink->name.'</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">';
                $dropend = $navlink->rght;
            }
        } else {
            if($navlink->rght + 1 == $dropend){
                echo'
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">'.$navlink->name.'</a>
        </div>
    </li>';
            } else {
                echo'
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">'.$navlink->name.'</a>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

---

[Pages/home]

```
use Cake\Cache\Cache;
use Cake\Core\Plugin;
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
use Cake\Error\Debugger;
use Cake\Http\Exception\NotFoundException;

$this->layout = "page";
?>
-------------------------navbar location------------------
    <div class="banner banner-main" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $this->Url->image('banner/1.jpg'); ?>')">
            <div class="container">........
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to import "view into view" ?

This concept is called `element` in CakePHP.

https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views.html#elements

It might be as well useful to move the logic for the nav output into a helper.

https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers

To pass the data to every page rendered pull it from the DB and set it to the view in the `beforeRender()` callback or your AppController.

https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers.html#request-life-cycle-callbacks

Comment: Also, if it's going to be on every page, it might be best to add it once in the layout, instead of every single view.

Comment: @Salines I don't like cells, they're like a cheat and you start so have logic scattered all around in places were it shouldn't be. If properly done the cells usually query just a repository or a call a domain object and this can be done from the controller as well pretty easy.

Comment: thanks to everyone, for now i´ll put the navbar to element and get data with TableRegistry.